# Type 'string | string[] | FormikErrors<any> | FormikErrors<any>[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to send my formik error to acomponent so that i can display error message to the user, but getting error

> Type 'string | string[] | FormikErrors | FormikErrors[]' is
> not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'string[]' is not assignable
> to type 'string'.

here is my code for below

```
export default function PlainInput({ type, placeholder, name, formik }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type={type}
        value={formik.values[name] || ""}
        name={name}
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          formik.setFieldValue(name, e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <ErrorMessage text={formik.errors[name]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

ErrorMessage.tsx

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  text: string ;
};

export default function ErrorMessage({ text }: Props) {
  return <p className="">{text}</p>;
}
```

I consoled the `typeof(formik.errors[name])` in my input component to check the type and it was coming as string so how do the typescript says Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.